# How to implement Loops in U-SQL

Tags: u-sql

Is is possible to implement Loops (while/for) in U-SQL without using C#. If no, can anyone share the c# syntax to implement loops in u-sql.

I am extracting files from a particular date to a date, but right now I am extracting this by writing file path manually.

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS dbo.ReadingConsolidated;  
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS dbo.ReadingConsolidated 
AS

EXTRACT     
        ControllerID int?,          
        sensorID int?,
        MeasureDate DateTime,
        Value float

FROM  
"adl://datalake.azuredatalakestore.net/2015/7/1/Reading.csv",
"adl://datalake.azuredatalakestore.net/2015/7/2/Reading.csv",
"adl://datalake.azuredatalakestore.net/2015/7/3/Reading.csv",
"adl://datalake.azuredatalakestore.net/2015/7/4/Reading.csv",
"adl://datalake.azuredatalakestore.net/2015/7/5/Reading.csv",
"adl://datalake.azuredatalakestore.net/2015/7/6/Reading.csv",
"adl://datalake.azuredatalakestore.net/2015/7/7/Reading.csv"
```

Note: these files are present in different folder.

Can above thing is possible using loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to use [virtual columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt621320.aspx), then rely on [partition elimination](http://www.slideshare.net/MichaelRys/usql-partitioned-data-and-tables-sqlbits-2016) so that only files matching predicates will actually be read (you can confirm that in the [job graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-data-lake-tools-get-started)).

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS dbo.ReadingConsolidated 
AS

EXTRACT     
        ControllerID int?,          
        ParameterID int?,
        MeasureDate DateTime,
        Value float,
        date DateTime
    FROM  
    "adl://datalake.azuredatalakestore.net/{date:yyyy}/{date:M}/{date:d}/Reading.csv";


@res =
    SELECT * FROM dbo.ReadingConsolidated
    WHERE date BETWEEN DateTime.Parse("2015/07/01") AND DateTime.Parse("2016/07/07");
```